# How do I resolve an error with the pNFS mapping daemon?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, nfs, services

I get an annoying error on my Ubuntu Server installation with `nfs-blkmap`. Running the command

```
~$ systemctl status nfs-blkmap.service
```

Yields the following

```json
× nfs-blkmap.service - pNFS block layout mapping daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-blkmap.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Wed 2022-07-13 16:16:36 UTC; 2 days ago
        CPU: 1ms

Jul 13 16:16:36 homeserver systemd[1]: Starting pNFS block layout mapping daemon...
Jul 13 16:16:36 homeserver blkmapd[1511]: open pipe file /run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/blocklayout failed: No such file or directory
Jul 13 16:16:36 homeserver systemd[1]: nfs-blkmap.service: New main PID 1511 does not exist or is a zombie.
Jul 13 16:16:36 homeserver systemd[1]: nfs-blkmap.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Jul 13 16:16:36 homeserver systemd[1]: Failed to start pNFS block layout mapping daemon.
```

I'll admit I haven't done much except some googling because I'm kinda afraid to mess up something. Could someone help me out?

**EDIT:** what I've tried so far:

1. Creating the following file did not work, because `/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/blocklayout` does *not* exist and trying to create it is impossible, due to ACL permissions (I think).

```
# /etc/systemd/system/nfs-blkmap.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/modprobe blocklayoutdriver
```

2. Renaming `nfs-blkmap.service` to `nfs-blkmap.service.old`. This one worked, but that's (of course) because the service technically "doesn't exist".

As far as I can tell, NFS seems to work regardless of the service failing or not existing, so maybe the package isn't maintained properly and/or not needed at all?

Also, the bug seems to be affecting both Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: What ubuntu release is this? Are you actively using `pNFS`, or did you just notice this error in your logs and started investigating what it was about?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I see this after an upgrade to 22.04.  The server is busy with other work, so I haven't tried a reboot yet.  Except for this error, everything seems in order on the system, but any attempt to mount a file system on a client just hangs forever.  I'm not well versed in the jungle of nfs-related daemons to know what to do.  Manually modprobing blocklayer changed the error to "killed by signal", if that helps.

Comment: Ok, rebooted the server, and things are working again.  I was unable to fix it by stopping and starting services (including rmmod/modprobing the modules), but at least things are back in apparent order.  I think I disabled the blockmap service, so unsure about the state of that.